# Draw wireless sensore network

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

How to route a path from the source node to the base station node?

[image: Routing path]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! And what please is your issue? Please show your code you have so far!

Answer (score 4):

If the problem is the path, here is an example.

Since Roland used TikZlings, I use TikZducks (with a suitable attacker):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{ducks}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, bending}
\tikzset{
    mymatr/.style = {
        matrix of nodes,
        nodes={inner sep=2pt,
            text centered,
            draw,
            circle
            }, 
            }
    }
    
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[mypath/.style={draw, -Triangle}]
\matrix[mymatr] (mym) {
    &&[10pt]&[10pt]&&&&[4pt]&&&&&&&&&&&&&[30pt]|[name=intermediate]|{}\\[10pt] 
    &&{}&&&&{}&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\[10pt] 
    &|[name=sourcenode, fill=black]|&&&& {}&&&&&&&&&&{}\\[6pt] 
    &&|[name=a]|&&&&&&&{}\\[4pt]  
    &&&&|[name=b]|\\ 
    &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&{}\\ 
    {}\\ 
    &&{}&&&&&|[name=c]|&&&&&\\[10pt]
    &{}&&&&&&&&&&&|[name=d]|\\[10pt]
    &&& {}&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&|[name=basestation, fill=red]|\\
    };
    \node[font=\small, anchor=north] at (basestation.south) {base station};   
    \node[anchor=210] (David) at ([xshift=3mm]basestation.east) {\includegraphics[width=.7cm]{David.png}};% put you image here
    \node[font=\small, anchor=south, inner sep=0pt] at (David.north) {attacker};
    \path (sourcenode.north east) -- ++(-1,0) pic[
        scale=.3,
        ] {duck} coordinate (duck);
    \node[font=\small, anchor=north east, inner ysep=0pt] at (sourcenode.west) {source node};
    \node[font=\small, anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt] at ([yshift=8mm]duck) {duck};
    \node[font=\small, anchor=west] (interlabel) at (intermediate.east) {Intermediate node};
    \node[font=\small, anchor=south east] (packedlegend) at (interlabel.north east) {Packed transmission};
    \draw[mypath] (packedlegend.west) to ++(-1,00);
    \node[font=\small, anchor=south east] (attacklegend) at (packedlegend.north east) {The attacker tracks the path hop by hop};
    \draw[mypath] (attacklegend.west) to[bend right] ++(-1,00);
    \draw[mypath] (sourcenode) -- (a);
    \draw[mypath] (a) -- (b);
    \draw[mypath] (b) -- (c);
    \draw[mypath] (c) -- (d);
    \draw[mypath] (d) -- (basestation);
    \draw[mypath] (a) to[bend right] (sourcenode);
    \draw[mypath] (b) to[bend right] (a);
    \draw[mypath] (c) to[bend right] (b);
    \draw[mypath] (d) to[bend right] (c);
    \draw[mypath] (basestation) to[bend right] (d);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: clearly a smart attacker, chose the optimum route

Answer (score 4):

A suggestion with tikzpeople and tikzlings:

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzlings}
\usepackage{tikzpeople}

\tikzset{
    blacks/.style = {circle,fill=black},
    whites/.style = {circle,draw=black},
    reds/.style = {circle,fill=red},
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}     
        %path nodes
        \node[blacks,label={[label distance=0.1cm]200:\tiny source node}] at (0,0) (a1) {};
        \node[whites] at (1,-1) (a2) {};
        \node[whites] at (3,-2) (a3) {};
        \node[whites] at (5,-3) (a4) {};
        \node[whites] at (6,-5) (a5) {};
        \node[reds,label={[label distance=0.1cm]-90:\tiny base station}] at (7,-7) (a6) {};
        
        %legend
        \draw[stealth-] (3,0.5) to[out=45,in=135] (3.5,0.5) node[right] {\tiny The attacker tracks the path hop by hop};
        \draw[-stealth] (3,0) -- (3.5,0) node[right] {\tiny Packet transmission path};
        \node[whites,label={[label distance=0.1cm]0:\tiny Intermediate node}] at (3.25,-0.5) {};
        
        %Panda
        \panda[above=of a1,yshift=0.5cm,scale=0.25];
        %attacker
        \node[right=of a6,guard,evil,mirrored,shield,sword,saturated,label={[label distance=0.1cm]90:\tiny attacker}] {};
        
        %path forward
        \foreach \x [remember=\x as \lastx (initially 1)] in {2,...,6}{
            \draw[-stealth] (a\lastx)--(a\x);}
        %path backward
        \foreach \y [remember=\y as \lasty (initially 6)] in {5,...,1}{
            \draw[-stealth] (a\lasty) [out=65, in=35] to  (a\y);}
        
        %random nodes
        \foreach \z  in {1,2,...,4}{
            \node[whites] at (8*rnd,-6*rnd) {};
            \node[whites] at (2*rnd,-6*rnd) {};
            \z
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]